# Passing a variable from Javascript into C# for use in SQL SELECT, then passing result back to Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, hidden-field

I am trying to run some code in my Code Behind to query my SQL Server (using a JavaScript variable) and then pass the result as an Integer back to my Javascript.

I have attempted to do this, by initially running some Javascript to get a variable for the SQL SELECT statement, then passing this to a hidden ASP field (currently a textbox for test purposes).

However everytime I run the code, refreshHTML(), the hidden field (textbox) value is blank and it returns the value 999999999.

When I run the application, I can see the textbox is populated with the correct value.

Here is my Code Behind in C#

```
    public int ucount
    {
    get
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(invoicenumberhidden.Text))
        {
            return 999999999;
        }

        else { 

        int invoicenumber = int.Parse(invoicenumberhidden.Text);

        string commandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS distinct_count FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [inv_section],[invoice_number], [cust_po] FROM [Indigo].[dbo].[invoice_items] WHERE invoice_number=" + invoicenumber + ") AS I;";
        string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Indigo2.Properties.Settings.Constr"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                int uniquecount = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                conn.Close();
                return uniquecount;
            }
        }          
    }
}
```

Here is my JavaScript which is triggered on an ASP OnClientClick event
            function refreshHtml()

```
        //Get Primary Key from Grid1
        var grid = jQuery("#<%= JQGrid1.ClientID %>");
        var rowKey = grid.getGridParam("selrow");

        document.getElementById('<%= invoicenumberhidden.ClientID %>').value = rowKey;

        var jsucount = '<%=this.ucount%>';
        alert(jsucount);
```

This is my relevant ASP code

```
<div hidden> <asp:Button ID="btnDownload" runat="server" OnClientClick="refreshHtml();" OnClick="btnDownloadButton_Click" Text="Export PDF"></asp:Button></div>
<asp:TextBox ID="invoicenumberhidden" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Have you looked in the Network tab of your browser's developer tools? What data is travelling back and forth? Is the SQL statement itself returning as expected?

Comment: The SQL statement never runs, the issue being the that the hiddenfield (textbox( value is NULL. Although when I run the application the Textbox shows as being populated.

Comment: As an aside, it's bad practice and plain dangerous to use non-parameterised variables in your SQL commands/Queries - you leave yourself wide open to SQL injection attack

Comment: Also, why not use a nullable int instead of returning 999999999?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `var jsucount = '<%=this.ucount%>';` with `var jsucount = document.getElementById('<%= invoicenumberhidden.ClientID %>').value;`.

You are facing this issue because in your html page you'll be having `var jsucount = 999999999`. Getting `999999999` value here because .net will set `'<%=this.ucount%>'` value when it send page to your browser. It will not reflect any further change carried out at server.

**Edit 2:**

As you want to do server trip for getting latest `ucount` value. You may try `PageMethods` for it.

You can move `ucount` logic to `method` like `GetUCount` and give `[WebMethod]` annotation. But you can not use controls here so you need to pass value of hidden field in parameter. And also need to make some change in javascript as described below.

**Code behind:**

```
[WebMethod]
public int GetUCount(string invoicenumberhidden)
{       
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(invoicenumberhidden))
    {
        return 999999999;
    }

    else 
    { 

        int invoicenumber = int.Parse(invoicenumberhidden);

        string commandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS distinct_count FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [inv_section],[invoice_number], [cust_po] FROM [Indigo].[dbo].[invoice_items] WHERE invoice_number=" + invoicenumber + ") AS I;";
        string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Indigo2.Properties.Settings.Constr"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                int uniquecount = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                conn.Close();
                return uniquecount;
            }
    }               
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
function refreshHtml() {
    //Get Primary Key from Grid1
    var grid = jQuery("#<%= JQGrid1.ClientID %>");
    var rowKey = grid.getGridParam("selrow");

    document.getElementById('<%= invoicenumberhidden.ClientID %>').value = rowKey;

    PageMethods.GetUCount(rowKey, onSuccess, onFailure);        
}

function onSuccess(result) {
    alert(result);
}

function onFailure(result) {
    alert("Failed!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Karan, but it is not the invoicenumberhidden value that I am trying to return. That value is sent to the code behind and used as part of the SQL statement. The value I want to return is the COUNT result from the SQL statement which is an int returned from the function, ucount

Comment: Updated my answer. I hope `PageMethods` can solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you PageMethods was what I needed :)